# Chrome Headless Print To PDF Has No Date and Time Stamp

Tags: google-chrome-headless

We have a project that uses Chrome Headless print to pdf to save a google search results to PDF.

Previously the generated PDF has a date and timestamp when it was created, but recently the PDF has no date and timestamp anymore.
Below is the sample command line:

chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="C:\Test\file32.pdf" https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+headless

I have tried setting the margins to default, but result is the same.

chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="C:\Test\file32.pdf" https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+headless

Comment: Hi K J, thank you for replying to my question. Yes, there is just on off switch for the headers. But we did not put the off flag for the headers so we are wondering why it is not appearing anymore.

Comment: Hi K J, yes we did not alter the CSS on the past to get the generated PDF with timestamps.